# Can not multiply or divide large or small floating numbers?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsnumber

Sorry for not posting any code. This question relates to division and multiplication by floating point numbers when working in xcode ios.

I have variable which i need to be divided by 2.055926336e+09. But unfortunately compiler does not divide it?

How i use it in the code

```
float variable1=((variable2)/(2.055926336e+09));
```

This is true for dividing with smaller values (Eg: - (1/(2.055926336e+09) )
What is the reason for this? Any efficient method to get this done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you getting an error message?  What is it?

Comment: What is the value of `variable2`, and what value do you get for `variable1`?

Comment: No error messages...! But it does not divide! When i tried with 2.055926336e+07, it works... So problem exist when the number becomes large.

Comment: variable2 lies in the range of 0 to 10.

Comment: Sorry, but “does not divide” does not tell us enough information.  Why do you think it “does not divide”?

Comment: Why do you think the answer is 0?  How are you printing the answer?

Answer (score 7):

I suspect the problem isn't in your computation.  It's in your printing.  You're probably trying to print the answer using a format like `%f`.  By default, `%f` prints 6 digits to the right of the decimal point.

The value of 10/2.055926336e+09 is 0.000000004863987500377056... which, as you can see, has more than 6 zeroes immediately following the decimal point.  If you try to format it using `%f`, you'll just get zero.

If you format it with `%e` (or `%g`) instead, the formatter will use scientific notation, and print the result as `4.863988e-10`, showing that the result is not zero.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "it does not divide", do you mean that the result it returns is `0`?

If so, your problem is floating point precision.  `10 / 2055926336` is an INCREDIBLY small number.  Floats only have 6 decimal places of precision, and aren't going to be able to store this accurately.

Your problem is not that the numbers are too large, but that the result is far too small.  Try using the `double` data type instead, but keep in mind that if your numbers get even smaller than this, it won't work (doubles have 15 digits of precision).

Comment: Yes. I think it may be the issue! So what is the possible way to get this done?

Comment: Edited my answer.  Use `double`s instead of `float`s.

Comment: 10 / 2055926336 will **not** be 0 in floating-point arithmetic.  At most, you would just need to increase precision when **formatting** the value when displaying it.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It divides out to `4.8639875 × 10-9`.  To my understanding, floats have 6 decimal points of precision only.  Can you expand upon your comment/correct my own?

Comment: @WendiKidd: `float`s have approximately 6 decimal digits of precision, but have a much larger *range*, approximately 3e38 down to 1e-38 (or 1e-45 if you include [denormal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalized_number)).

Comment: @WendiKidd An `int` is automatically promoted to a `double` when the other operand is a `double`.

Comment: @sam: That doesn't make any sense.  This answer is factually incorrect, so I can't believe that it fixed your problem (unless you haven't described your problem correctly...).

Answer (score 0):

@rob mayoff's answer is quite valid, but you might not be interested in showing the scientific result to the user. My take on that is to break the large number into two strings and concat them like below

```
-(NSString*) stringWithLargeNumber:(double)large
{
    int fraction1 = large/10000;
    float fraction2 = large-fraction1;
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%.2f", fraction1, fraction2];
}
```

Hope this helps